# In React, how do I call a function in one component (which is being rendered with React Router) from another component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Could really use some help with this roadblock. I have pretty basic React app I'm building which has the following components and structure:

```
App
   Nav
   Main
      PageOne
          PageOneDetail
      ...
```

I would like to be able to invoke a function in Nav from any of the components in the component structure. My understanding so far is I could do this with `props`. I know how I could do it with a child component, but not sure how to achieve it with grandchildren or sibling components.

I'm trying to stick to functional components and use vanilla React and I'm using React Router to render components with Route.

Here's a simplified version of the code I have:

**App.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import Nav from './Nav'
import Main from './Main'


class App extends Component {

    render() {
        <Nav />
        <Main />
    }
}

export default App
```

**Nav.js**

```
import React from 'react'
import { NavLink } from 'react-router-dom'

const Nav = (props) => {
    
    function doSomethingToNav() {

         // here's where I want to change appearance or do whatever to the nav
         // I want to be able to use this function from within my Nav component
         // but also want to be able to call it from any another component
    }

    return(
        <nav>
            <NavLink to="/pageone">Page One</NavLink>
            <NavLink to="/pagetwo">Page Two</NavLink>
        </nav>
    )
}

export default Nav
```

**Main.js**

```
import React from 'react'
import { Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom'
import PageOne from './PageOne'
import PageOne from './PageTwo'

const Main = (props) => {

    return (
            
    <main>
        <Switch>
            <Route exact path='/pageone'><PageOne /></Route>
            <Route exact path='/pagetwo'><PageTwo /></Route>
        </Switch>
    </main>
}   

export default Main
```

**PageOne.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { Switch, Route, BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom'
import SomeListOfItems from 'SomeListOfItems'

export default class PageOne extends Component {

    render(){
        <BrowserRouter>
            <Switch>
                <Route>
                    <SomeListOfItems />
                </Route>
                <Route path="/pageone/:number/" component={PageOneItem} />
                // I also want to call the doSomethingToNav method when I route to the 
                // PageOneItem component

            </Switch>
        </BrowserRouter>
    }
}
```

**PageOneItem.js**

```
import React from 'react'
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom'


const PageOneDetail = (props) => {
    
    return(
        <div>
            <Link to='/pageone'>Close</Link> 
            // I want to call doSomethingToNav function when I close this component. 
            // Close, in this case, is just routing back to /pageone
            <p>Some content...</p>
        </div>
    )
}

export default PageOneDetail
```

Comment: Since both the Nav and Main are siblings , you can either move that function to your App.js so that you can pass that function as props or you can use context .

Comment: if you are not going to use any props passed in `Nav` component inside `doSomethingToNav` then I would recommend to move the function in a separate file and import it whereve you need

Comment: to call any function on "close" (unmount) any component use `React.useEffect(() => {return () => doSomethingToNav()})` and on "route" to any route (mount) use `React.useEffect(() => {doSomethingToNav()}, [])`

Comment: Thanks all. A combination of your comments and Mario's answer below helped me figure this out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could go with solution to have context and have all wrapped components to access it with `useContext` hook.

This is how you can use it:

**App component**

```js
import React, { Component, useState } from 'react';
import Nav from './Nav';
import Main from './Main';

const AppContext = createContext({
  executeNavigationFunction: () => {},
  setExecuteNavigationFunction: (navFunction: () => void) => {},
});
const App = () => {
  const [executeNavigationFunction, setExecuteNavigationFunction] = useState(() => {});

  return (
    <AppContext.Provider value={{ executeNavigationFunction, setExecuteNavigationFunction }}>
      <Nav />
      <Main />
    </AppContext.Provider>
  );
};

export default App;
```

**Nav component**

```js
import React, {useEffect, useContext, useEffect} from 'react';
import { NavLink } from 'react-router-dom';
import AppContext from 'app';

const Nav = (props) => {
  const { setExecuteNavigationFunction } = useContext(AppContext);

  function doSomethingToNav() {
    // here's where I want to change appearance or do whatever to the nav
    // I want to be able to use this function from within my Nav component
    // but also want to be able to call it from any another component
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    setExecuteNavigationFunction(doSomethingToNav)
  }, [setExecuteNavigationFunction])

  return (
    <nav>
      <NavLink to="/pageone">Page One</NavLink>
      <NavLink to="/pagetwo">Page Two</NavLink>
    </nav>
  );
};

export default Nav;
```

**PageOneItem component**

```js
import React, {useEffect, useContext} from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import AppContext from 'app';

const PageOneDetail = (props) => {
  const { executeNavigationFunction } = useContext(AppContext);

  useEffect(() => {
    executeNavigationFunction();
  }, []);
  return (
    <div>
      <Link to="/pageone">Close</Link>
      // I want to call doSomethingToNav function when I close this component. // Close, in this case, is just routing
      back to /pageone
      <p>Some content...</p>
    </div>
  );
};

export default PageOneDetail;
```

In this way you can use any data from any part of the app in any part of the app.

It may seem a bit hacky, but if you are not using some global state lib, Context is the way to go.

Comment: Thank you very much, Mario! I went this route with a slightly different implementation. I found trying to create a context with a method to be a little too complicated. Instead, I just used context to keep track of the nav state. And depending on which component is loaded, I'd change the state accordingly.

Comment: No problem. Glad i nudged you in the right direction. Yes, you can go in that route better, sine it seems too overwhelming to set method and pass it back to context.